# How to give connection string as a key value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to  give connection string as a key.
So I write in web.config this code.

```
    <add key="connectstring" value="Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=DBName; Integrated Security=False; providerName=System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </appSettings>
```

but there is error and it says

```
Keyword not supported: 'providername'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'providername'.

Source Error:

Line 28:             SqlConnection conn;
Line 29:             conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectstring"].ToString());
Line 30:                 
Line 31:
```

How can I solve it??

Comment: **providerName** is not part of your connection string

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ConfigurationManager object:

```
string connectionString 
    = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;

<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" 
        connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyDB;Data Source=MyPC;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<connectionStrings>
```

To use appSettings:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.Appsettings.Get("connectstring");
```

Comment: But there is another error   -- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:


Line 25:             }
Line 26: 
Line 27:             string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectstring"].ToString();
Line 28:             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164439/reading-and-writting-keys-to-appsettings-in-webconfigeditor

Answer (score 1):

```
<appSettings>
<add key="connectstring" value="Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=DBName; Integrated Security=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

separate **providerName** in your value

NOTE: There is an error in your value, add a double qoutation after ***False;***