# How to connect to local database and update a dataset in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, visual-studio, mdf

I have stored some products (a product contains: unique id - primary key, name, price, quantity) in a local database file (Stock.mdf, table for the products is called 'table').

The file is in my project folder in Visual Studio. When someone call an action in the form (WPF), a entry should be updated (new quantity).

In my C# code file i use the following code to connect to the database:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
               AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Stock.mdf; |
               Integrated Security=True;
               Connect Timeout=30;
               User Instance=True";
//Do i need the connect timeout? Found it somewhere in the web
```

I know that I can update the table in SQL with this command:

```
UPDATE table
SET Quantity=newQuantity
WHERE Id=GivenId;
```

How can I connect to the local dataset and update a product with the new quantity in c#?

Comment: Are you getting an error or anything?  Or are you just asking how to perform an update in c#?

Comment: @evan-l I ask how to connect to an local database

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please make use of `using` statements.  They will ensure that `IDisposable.Dispose()` is called.

Written from memory:

```
string cs = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
           AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Stock.mdf; |
           Integrated Security=True;
           Connect Timeout=30;
           User Instance=True";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE table SET Quantity=@q WHERE Id=@Id", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@q", newQuanity);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", GivenId);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

> Do i need the connect timeout? Found it somewhere in the web

The default is fine for most circumstances.

Note that it is better practice to place the connection string in your app.config (or web.config, for web apps).

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyConnectionName" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
           AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Stock.mdf; |
           Integrated Security=True;
           Connect Timeout=30;
           User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then access it like:

```
string cs = 
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: I have added the connectionstring in the app.config: '<connectionStrings>
      <add name="StockConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Stock.mdf;
                Integrated Security=True;
                Connect Timeout=30;
                User Instance=True; 
                providerName=System.Data.SqlClient;" />
    </connectionStrings>' 

When I try it, I get the exception "Keyword not supported 'providername'"
The Exception is thrown at this line: 'using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))'

Comment: @Hack4Life: Make sure *providerName* is a separate attribute.  That is, double-check your quotes match what is in my answer.  Someone else got the exact same error by having providerName inside the quotes for connectionString, instead of separate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242429/how-to-give-connection-string-as-a-key-value

Comment: Okey, thanks @eric-j! Now I don't get an error. I have surrounded the whole block with try/catch. When i set an brakpoint and run the programit will not work. When it comes to con.Open() the program stops without an exception.

Comment: The program will not just *stop* at con.Open().  The code could pause up to 30 seconds (the connection timeout), but will continue either normally or by throwing an Exception at that point.

Comment: Okay, now i got the error 26. LineNumber: 0, Source: .Net SQLClient Data Provider.. Do I need Microsoft SQL Server for this? I just have Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Comment: I've changed Data Source=.\SQLExpress; to Data Source=(local); now I get Error 40...

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the Sql database using C# in Microsoft Visual studio,you have to manually add the `System.Data.SqlSeverCe.dll` name reference as follow:

- Right-click on your Project >>> **Add Reference**
- Browse >>> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL server Compact edition\v3.5\Desktop
- Load >>> the System.Data.SqlSeverCe.dll >>> **Add**